# Are there any alternative to insert explicit value for identity column than setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. Both have same column name. For expanding purpose I need to migrate data from one table to another table. I wrote the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(primaryKey,column1, column2)
SELECT * 
FROM Table2
WHERE (<condition>)
```

which is causing an error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

When I google for it, all people have mentioned to use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [spider3].[Table1] ON
```

But there are drawbacks mentioned for that. Even though this feature is valid only for a connection, we are unable to have the `IDENTITY_INSERT` thing as `ON` for more than one table. So I'm looking for alternatives.

Can anyone suggest alternative solutions? Can I use 'as' keyword in query it self to resolve this problem? If so how?

Comment: "we are unable to have the IDENTITY_INSERT thing as ON for more than one table" - since any `INSERT` operation can only affect one table, and you can run more `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statements between `INSERT` statements, I don't see how it's possibly an issue that it can only be set for one table at a time.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the identity property of the field so your primary key would be an integer field as any other ?.

Comment: The options are: **(1)** use `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, **(2)** not trying to insert values into an `IDENTITY` column (let SQL Server handle that), or **(3)** make your column **NOT** be an `IDENTITY` column ...

Comment: Normally you'd turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on, do your insert, turn off `IDENTITY_INSERT` and continue. As to any other way, it would greatly surprise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some insert statements calculating in the possibility of an identity insert. These can be run in a batch and will perform the `IDENTITY_INSERT` dynamically. I normally use a script to generate those statements.

```
IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[Production].[ScrapReason]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[ScrapReason] ON; INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2014].[Production].[ScrapReason] ([ScrapReasonID], [Name], [ModifiedDate]) SELECT * FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Production].[ScrapReason]; IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[Production].[ScrapReason]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[ScrapReason] OFF; 
IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[HumanResources].[Shift]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [HumanResources].[Shift] ON; INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Shift] ([ShiftID], [Name], [StartTime], [EndTime], [ModifiedDate]) SELECT * FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Shift]; IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[HumanResources].[Shift]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [HumanResources].[Shift] OFF; 
IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[Production].[ProductCategory]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[ProductCategory] ON; INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2014].[Production].[ProductCategory] ([ProductCategoryID], [Name], [rowguid], [ModifiedDate]) SELECT * FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Production].[ProductCategory]; IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[Production].[ProductCategory]'), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[ProductCategory] OFF;
```

In this case the select and insert both happen into `[AdventureWorks2014]` which is obviously normally not the case, but I currently only had one DB avail to demonstrate. If you're interested in how to generate those, see below.

```
DECLARE @v_SourceDatabase      NVARCHAR(250); 
DECLARE @v_DestinationDatabase NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @t_TablesToProcess     TABLE (FullTableName NVARCHAR(250),
                                      TableName     NVARCHAR(250),
                                      TableSchema   NVARCHAR(250),
                                      ColumnList    NVARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @v_ColumnList         NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @v_TableName          NVARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @v_TableSchema        NVARCHAR(250);

-- -------------------------------------- --
-- Set Source & destination database here --
-- -------------------------------------- --

SET @v_SourceDatabase      = N'AdventureWorks2014';
SET @v_DestinationDatabase = N'AdventureWorks2014';

-- Generate tables to process
INSERT INTO @t_TablesToProcess
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME(syssch.name), '.', QUOTENAME(systab.name)) FullTableName
     , systab.name
     , syssch.name
     , NULL
FROM   sys.tables systab
INNER JOIN sys.schemas syssch
  ON syssch.schema_id = systab.schema_id
WHERE type = 'U';

DECLARE TableList CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT TableName, TableSchema
  FROM @t_TablesToProcess;

OPEN TableList;
FETCH NEXT FROM TableList INTO @v_TableName, @v_TableSchema;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @v_ColumnList = CONCAT(@v_ColumnList, QUOTENAME(column_name), ', ')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @v_TableName
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @v_TableSchema

  SET @v_ColumnList = LEFT(@v_ColumnList, LEN(@v_ColumnList) - 1);

  UPDATE @t_TablesToProcess
  SET ColumnList = @v_ColumnList
  WHERE TableName = @v_TableName
    AND TableSchema = @v_TableSchema;

  SET @v_ColumnList = '';

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableList INTO @v_TableName, @v_TableSchema;
END 

CLOSE TableList;
DEALLOCATE TableList;

-- Generate insert statements
SELECT CONCAT(N'IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''', FullTableName, '''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT ', FullTableName, N' ON; '
            , N'INSERT INTO ', QUOTENAME(@v_DestinationDatabase), '.', FullTableName
            , N' (', ColumnList, N')'
            , N' SELECT * FROM ', QUOTENAME(@v_SourceDatabase), N'.', FullTableName, N';'
            , N' IF (OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''', FullTableName, '''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1) SET IDENTITY_INSERT ', FullTableName, N' OFF; ')
FROM @t_TablesToProcess;
```

Small remark: wrote this script without pulling it through any real testing. Some things can clearly be improved. The way I handled the building of column names is less than ideal. Using `XML PATH` & `STUFF` would be a better option:

```
SELECT Chars = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [Char]
    FROM dbo.Chars
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

It's a nudge in some possible direction. If I ever find the time I'll probably rework this into a more fool proof / generic solution.

As to another way to do identity inserts without using `IDENTITY_INSERT`, I doubt there are any.